# Pop up window with data from another spreadsheet

Tags: database, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to build a master spreadsheet in Google Sheets to call up data (not import data, just make a quick view in a popup window) for individuals from other spreadsheets.  E.g. my master sheet has a column for therapists, a column for certifications, a column for periodic reviews, etc.  All of these columns correspond to other sheets within the project that list out the certifications for each individual therapist, the periodic reviews for each individual therapist, etc.

I want to be able to click in the cell where "Mary" intersects with "Certifications" and see a small popup window that shows me Mary's record in the Certifications page.

I tried a couple of functions pasted from other pages (it's been a long time since I've coded), but none worked.  This seems like a simple database-like call, so I hope the solution is also simple.  I appreciate any help offered.  (My clinic doesn't have an in-house IT person, so I'm trying to help where I can.)

Comment: There's no event associated with click on a cell.  It would be possible to do with a dialog that reads the current cell and determines the header title and the therapist for that row.  I don't know how to  do it without some coding though.  It seems simple to me. But if you've never coded in Javascript or any c like language it might not be so simple at first.

Comment: OK.  Could I turn the cells into an array of buttons?  Then pressing a button could summon a function to call the record.  (I'm trying to keep the interface very simple for my boss and coworkers.  Buttons would be nicely intuitive.)

Comment: You could do that.  You could also put checkboxes in the  cells and access the functions via an onEdit() trigger.

Comment: If you want to use Triggers I recommend you to check [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) and if you want to use buttons you could check [Clickable images and drawings in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets)